# How does flatMap execute code synchronously?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am using `flatMap` right now because it can process asynchronous code synchronously (as in one-by-one with values from previous result), but I do not know how it is doing this. The documentation doesn't seem to explain that this behavior is part of the operator.

On the RxJS doc `flatMap` is defined as:

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the
>   output Observable.

I need to process a combination of `observable`, `promise`, and `synchronous` code within my pipe. Most of the time piped data depends on its predecessor:

```
from(
  // asyncrhonously fetch data from server
  fetchDataAsync(credentials) // returns an Observable
).pipe(
  flatMap((data) => {
    // process the data with a promise
    return from(processDataAsync(data))
  }),
  flatMap((data) => {
    // sanitize the data with synchronous fn
    return of(sanitizeDataSync(data))
  }),
  flatMap((data) => {
    // store the data in local storage with a promise
    return from(storeDataAsync(data))
  })
)
```

`flatMap` works, but I don't know how or why. How I can find this behavior in other operators?

---

Basically I want the benefit of observable streams that runs like your typical async function. What is the `RX-way` of doing this?

```
async function fn() {
  // asyncrhonously fetch data from server
  const fetched = await fetchDataAsync(credentials).toPromise()
  // process the data with a promise
  const processed = await processDataAsync(fetched)
  // sanitize the data with synchronous fn
  const santized = sanitizeDataSync(processed)
  // store the data in local storage with a promise
  return await storeDataAsync(santized)
}
```

Comment: you wrapping it in of() turns the synchronous function in an asynchronous function. of() tells rxJS to treat it like an observable.

Comment: flatMap requires an observable to be returned. What operator should I be using instead while guaranteeing data has been processed?

Comment: swtichMap or concatMap may be what you're after. it's unclear though what you're trying to do with those from operators.  a better explanation of what processData and storeData and sanitizeData do adn return may help.

Answer (score 1):

The `flatMap` operator does not execute code sychronously: every time it receives an event of type `Observable`, it subscribes to it and emits its events in the same returning `Observable`. By the way it's been renamed to `mergeMap` in the most recent versions, which describes its behavior better.

Comment: Synchronous in the sense that returning values are passed to the next flatMap for execution. It's import that I can process data and their returned values one-by-one.

Comment: I would use the word sequentially, but that doesn't imply the values are fully returned, just execution order.

Comment: The `pipe` keyword guarantees the execution order. So the only thing you're looking for is an operator that emits the only event of your Observables created `from` your Promises. In that regard, `concatMap`, `mergeMap` or `switchMap` will perform equally.